# Ubuntu 16.04 WIFI will always disconnect by itself after more than half an hour

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless

I have a fairly fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 (I have steamcmd for an ark server and that's about it). I have ports forwarded to the computer for the ark server but the ark server doesn't work if the wifi always randomly disconnects, which is where my problem begins.
It connects fine (to my telstra router/modem), all working and then about half an hour to multiple hours later (not exactly sure the time because I have the screen off but its definitely more than half an hour) the wifi dialogue will show up asking for authentication and then it will disconnect from the wifi. I have to go on the computer and press the connect button to connect back to the wifi (the correct password is still registered). I have tried looking for a fix but I can't find anything anywhere. My power settings are set to turn the screen off after about 5 minutes or so and it never goes to sleep.
Does anyone have any idea on why this is happening?
(the computer is an intel NUC https://ark.intel.com/products/83254/Intel-NUC-Kit-NUC5i5RYK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computer has integrated Intel Wireless-AC 7265 module according to official Intel specifications. The Intel wireless modules have default region (country) embedded setting in its configuration "world" (00), which can restrict connecting for some wireless standards, e.g. it can disable IEEE 802.11ас standard in some cases. First of all create `/etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf` file:

```
sudo touch /etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf
```

Add the following line to the file:

```
options cfg80211 ieee80211_regdom=UA
```

where `UA` is region (country) code. Replace the code with some unrestricitve country - see [List of countries](https://w.wol.ph/2015/08/28/maximum-wifi-transmission-power-country/).

Reboot your computer and see if problem is solved. Also check if contry code is set correctly:

```
iw reg get
```

If the problem hasn't gone away, the next possibility is to disable power management for wireless card. Check the state of wireless card power management:

```
iwconfig
```

If the last command returns for you wireless card `Power Management:on` - disable it temporarily (until next system reboot):

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

where `wlan0` is name of your wireless module, replace it if it differs for you.
Check power management status again:

```
iwconfig
```

Don't reboot computer and observe if the problem gone away. If power management disabling has helped, make the setting permanent - open in your favorite text editor (let it be vim for instance) file:

```
vim /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

and in the line `wifi.powersave = 3` replace `3` with `2`, so after editing the line will be `wifi.powersave = 2`. Reboot your computer and check power management status again:

```
iwconfig
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80016/discussion-on-answer-by-wiking-ubuntu-16-04-wifi-will-always-disconnect-by-itsel).

Comment: After adding in the BSSID, below that there was "device" and I changed that to wlp2s0 because for some reason it wasn't set to that either.